# Store XML from Google Apps Script to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I used the XML Service of GAS to get the content of a Spreadsheet in XML format. Everything works fine and I get the most beautiful XML in the console.
Now I would like to write that XML to a file and save it in my Google Drive. I cannot really figure out how to do that though.

I understand that I could use ContentService to deliver XML to the Browser but that appears to be a bit cumbersome given the objective.

Thank you all in advance for your help. :-)

Alex

Comment: This is trivial if you google 5 minutes in the documentation. See DriveApp and come back with code if you cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are in luck! This is the bread and butter of Google Apps Script. There are two built in services.

DriveApp

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

And the Drive Service:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive

The very basics would look like:

```
var myNewFileObject = DriveApp.createFile("myXmlFile.xml", xmlContent, "text/xml");
```